# World Remained Those of Combination?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, word-usage, translation

I read one book, anyone could describe the concept meaning by following sentence:

"In the sixth century, at the very close of the classical period, the great libraries of the Mediterranean world remained those of Constantinople and Alexandria"

My problem is via by "remained those of" it means: remaining libraries from Constantinople and Alexandria ?!

Comment: (1) I seem to remember that both Alexandria and Constantinople had one famous library apiece. (2) A paraphrase is "the libraries of Constantinople and Alexandria were still the only great / significant ones to be found in the Mediterranean world".

Comment: It is depressing to see that there are a million sites all copying the same sentence from one anther, apparently.-- I would simply think that yet another "of" is missing: "**Of** the great libraries of the Mediterranean world remained those of Constantinople and Alexandria." Certainly not elegant -- one could say "in the Mediterreanean word" instead. But the first "of" is needed to indicate that the remaining libraries were only a part *of* a former whole.

Comment: And also I cannot resist to share the quip that "the most significant Roman contribution to our culture was to burn down the library of Alexandria" (even though that is probably not quite true on a number of levels).

Comment: I would say that the "Of the great libraries of the Mediterranean world remained those of Constantinople and Alexandria." is wrong. Or partial/missing context.

That first of Isn't needed, because of the word remained - the subject is clearly visible, and given - the great libraries of the Mediterranean.

It's a switch up on the "X and Y remained of Z" - "Z, remained those of X and Y". The statement is missing a , at best, and the of at maximum.

Comment: @Sakatox I complete it.

Comment: see the complete sentence @PeterA.Schneider

Comment: @user4249446 Maybe i'm seeing a typo still, or reading it wrong. In 6 century - 6th or six centuries? My other guess is that the source is of non-native English/foreign written media.

Either way, i stand by my answer.

Comment: Yeah Correct it in Question.  @Sakatox

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The great libraries of the ancient (Mediterranean) world were the Great Library of Alexandria and the library of Constantinople. At the end of the period, the great libraries were still those of Constantinople and Alexandria (though other libraries existed). In the sixth century, at the close of the classical period, the great libraries of the Mediterranean world remained those of Constantinople and Alexandria.

Answer (score 0):

Mix the structure up a bit.

The concept is of "loss":
The chosen words imply a tragedy of sort, that to this day, still hurt - a play on the feelings of the reader, which in turn carries a separate thought of what could have been.

It's another of those less than subtle implications.
So, all in all, yes, you did understand correctly, but missed the "emotional" value of it.

Mediterranean libraries remaining are in Constantinople and Alexandria - this lacks the emotional value.

EDIT: Since i didn't clarify enough and there were some comments here and there. The extra context does change my answer a bit. Either in the 6th Century or in six centuries, it's of a historical loss.

Comment: see edited questions.

Comment: I stand by my answer, the extra context isn't modifying the perceived or implied loss. :) @user4249446